# PRISM 5 : IConfirmNavigationRequest methods called more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm using `PRISM` and Unity extensions.

A WPF button command invokes the following code and displays dialog :

```
 private void LaunchDialog() 
 {
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new  Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
        bootstrapper.MyShell.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        bootstrapper.MyShell.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I click `LaunchDialog` for the first time, the `PRISM` navigation methods `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo` calls once. I close the dialog,

When I click `LaunchDialog` for the next time, the `PRISM` navigation methods `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo` gets called twice. I close the dialog,

If I click `LaunchDialog` for third time, the `PRISM` navigation methods `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo` gets called thrice.I close the dialog,

How do I get rid of this behavior? So that Navigation methods are called only once as launched for the first time even if the user clicks `LaunchDialog` multiple times.

Comment: I think your dialog instance is not getting disposed properly. Check for some events or any static references.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you create a bootstrapper and run it in a method that's called on a button click in your already running application? Well, then it's a totally wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

I just added bootstrapper.Container.RemoveAllExtensions()  to get rid of this behavior.

```
private void LaunchDialog() 
{
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new  Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
        bootstrapper.MyShell.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        bootstrapper.MyShell.ShowDialog();
        bootstrapper.Container.RemoveAllExtensions();
}
```